# VueJs 3: What kind of components should be loaded globally to improve the performance

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-component

With vue3 we can implement components globally which means that they're also implemented if they're not used.
My thought was to implement layout-components (grid,row,col) globally, but they're not used in every component like f.e. at input fields.

Perhaps we're here on a finetuning level but the question is when should I avoid to implement global components and when should I implement them?

Comment: The name quite speaks for itself. Use global components when you need them in (almost) every place, and avoid using global components when there is only one place that utilize them

Comment: @HuyPhạm So at least you can give me no real advice. It's just a kind of feeling?

Comment: This is irrelevant to the performance. This saves some time on import management but requires an undetermined amount of time for the maintenance. It's generally a good practice to avoid global things for the same reason as global variables are avoided.

Answer (score 1):

The question is - what do you need that for?

- To remove `import` line in a component? Use two `auto-imports` packages, see [Vitesse template](https://github.com/antfu/vitesse)
- To make load times faster? Vite will pack it optimally no matter if you have global components or not - I'd expect Vite to guess global components itself and pack into common-things.js

> https://vuejs.org/guide/components/registration.html#local-registration
> Global registration prevents build systems from removing unused components (a.k.a "tree-shaking"). If you globally register a component but end up not using it anywhere in your app, it will still be included in the final bundle.

So, I'd recommend [unplugin-vue-components](https://github.com/unplugin/unplugin-vue-components) to make components "global" rather then actually making them global